# How to create a string slice from arithmetic in one line?

Tags: rust

In rust, how to create a string slice `&str`, from a arithmetic expression, say `1 * 2 * 3`, in one line?

i.e. the following code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = vec!["x", &(1 * 2 * 3).to_string()];
    println!("{:?}", a)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7231fc0d03c8d40010ade793a87311fe)

produces the following error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:4:24
  |
4 |     let a = vec!["x", &(1 * 2 * 3).to_string()];
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |                        |
  |                        creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
5 |     println!("{:?}", &a);
  |                      -- borrow later used here
  |
  = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

But doing as the compiler suggests would require an extra statement:

```rust
let num = (1 * 2 * 3).to_string();
let a = vec!["x", &num];
```

Is there a way to get rid of the `let num = …` statement?

Comment: @Jmb now it doesn't ...

Comment: Do you want a string representation of the expression value, or the expression itself? (1 * 2 * 3) should be `"1 * 2 * 3"` or `"6"`?

Comment: @YuriKovalenko `"6"`

Comment: You can't without a proc macro for example. You need at least a temporary variable which you can store the `String` in. The other solution would be to convert "x" into a string, by using `to_string` on it.

Comment: Is there a specific motivation for wanting to do this in one line? Knowing that might allow people to provide alternative approaches.

Comment: Also, is there a specific reason you need it as a string-slice? Using `String` instead would make it work in one line by converting the `"x"` to a `String`

Comment: sometime compiler can but not this time.